# MYSQL order by a column from another table row count

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table : code  and code_like

code table

```
code_id | code_name
---------------
1       | pagination
2       | function 
3       | script
```

code_like table

```
like_id | code_id(id of code table)
1       | 3
2       | 1
3       | 3
4       | 2
5       | 1
6       | 3
```

I want to sort `code table` by row count of `code_like` table

Example :

```
I want result like
 (1)  script     (1st because 3 times in code_like table)
 (2)  pagination (2nd because 2 times in code_like table)
 (3)  function   (3rd because 1 time in code_like table)
```

Comment: primary keys of two tables are not have same name.Change id as c_id in code_like table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join and order by count of code likes

```
select c.*
from code c
left join code_like l on c.id = l.code_id
group by c.id
order by count(*) desc
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d91f/2)

Answer (score 2):

Here you need COUNT, JOIN and GROUP BY

```
SELECT c.code_name, count(*) AS rowcount 
FROM code c LEFT JOIN code_like l ON l.code_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY rowcount DESC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c60f2/2)

Comment: Added an sqlfiddle to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM code_like WHERE code_like.code_id = code.id ) AS like
FROM code 
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM code_like WHERE code_like.code_id = code.id ) DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *
, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM code_like WHERE code_like.code_id = code.id ) AS like
FROM code 
) AS code_was_like 
ORDER BY like DESC
```

I hope this help.

Comment: There is no order by in your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c . * 
FROM code AS c
INNER JOIN code_like AS cl ON cl.code_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY COUNT( cl.code_id ) DESC
```